# A smily murderer

Tags: visual, knowledge, rebus

[image: A smily murderer]

This may be ve-e-e-ery easy, though it requires basic knowledge of popular culture.

Hint:

> [image: wut]

Comment: Easy, it's gun bang fearful ip

Comment: Gun shot. Scared, I pee. ***NAILED IT.***

Comment: @Rubio Duck wrench tankle?

Comment: *basic knowledge of popular culture* -I think this needs more clarification than any other hints.

Comment: @Sid The hint seems to mean the *popular culture* refer to a song or music

Comment: @Sid The answer is a person, who is famous among the internet, so I suppose it suits for 'popular culture'.

Comment: @Zachstein actually not :|

Comment: Constructive criticism to help for next time: what each image represents is rather dubious and the answer is quite disappointing. Maybe try next time to think of better images to represent each part. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

> PewDiePie

because

> the gun goes "pew pew pew!"

and then

> the scared face dies because gun shot

finally

> pi is backwards, but hey, it's still pi.

Comment: you've made it! :D

Answer (score 1):

It can be

> **Executorship**

Explanation

> Firing gun - Executor
>  Scared Smiley - sh(like shhhh)
>  Reversed Pi - IP